# Mac cxFreeze app quits unexpectedly when trying to open

Tags: python, macos, cx-freeze

I am trying to ***convert a python script to a mac app*** so I can distribute it. I'm using cxFreeze to do this. After creating the app, I try to open it but it says the app quit unexpectedly and shows some report.


(code signature invalid (errno=1)

usr/local/lib/Python (no such file)

[image: mac report]

---

my script ***at.py***:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import font
window = tk.Tk()
width=1
window.title('test')
window.geometry("425x500")

label_speed = tk.Label(
    text="Speed"
)

label_speed.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan = 5, stick="w")
window.mainloop()
```

And then my ***setup.py***

```
from cx_Freeze import Executable, setup

base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"

executables = [Executable("at.py", base=base)]

setup(
    name="test",
    version="0.1",
    description="just for testing",
    executables=executables,
)
```

I used the following commands to make the mac bundle or app.

`python3 setup.py build` then
`python3 setup.py bdist_dmg`
I had to use python3 instead of python because it wasn't working for me.

Thanks in advance for any tips and answers

Answer (score 1):

There might be two different things going on. The first thing I know I have run into with cx_freeze is that it tried to map to where it thinks the python 2.x folder should be even if I specify to run on python 3.x. The other thing might be it was downloaded on to a different path. type $ where python to see where the file path should be. If you do $ open $FILEPATH and you see that its using python3 it might be worth reaching out to the maintainer of cx_freeze and see if they have any advice.